# How to animate a View object when toggling its visibility state?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

[image: ViewGroup object transitioning between gone and visible state]

I have a ViewGroup object for which I toggle its visibility value between "gone" and "visible" at the press of a "down" and "up" button respectively. When the ViewGroup object comes into or out of view I want it to look like it is being dropped/slid down and raised/slid up (as in the picture above). Anyone have any ideas or leads as to how this can be achieved?

(Extra note: The ViewGroup object that is coming into and out of view contains Buttons etc that need to be interacted with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a SlidingDrawer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

```
<SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />

     <ViewGroup
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </SlidingDrawer>
```

Simple as that. The Handle is your button. You'll have to play with orientation and sizes to get in where you want on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for this Blundell. Appreciate it. Read the API spec and looks like what I need. Gonna give it a try mid-week (if not earlier) and will report back and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, seems SlidingDrawer is exactly what I need... almost :( SlidingDrawer has two options _only_: (1) vertical orientation such that handle is slid up to reveal content; (2) horizontal orientation such that handle is slid left to reveal content. Strangely no vertical slide down or horizontal slide right option?! Blundell (or anyone else), know how to get SlidingDrawer to slide down or even any other tool that can do the job?..

Comment: I've marked this answer as the accepted answer though the SlidingDrawer falls slightly short of what I require, but I'm creating a new thread for that discussion here: [Changing alignment (left, right etc) of SlidingDrawer handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649545/changing-alignment-left-right-etc-of-slidingdrawer-handle)