# Changing alignment (left, right etc) of SlidingDrawer handle

Tags: android, android-sliding

(I've seen a few related questions but no answers so putting this out on the odd chance someone has done something similar or can point me in the right direction...)

The standard Android SlidingDrawer (and also [Alessandro Crugnola's multi-direction variant](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) which I'm using) centre-aligns the handle. Has anyone implemented a SlidingDrawer which offers the option to right or left align the handle?.. or anyone have any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out. In the `mVertical` is true condition of the `onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)` method of SlidingDrawer (or whatever variant of SlidingDrawer you're using), you should find the following line of code...

```
handleLeft = (width - childWidth) / 2;
```

... which centre-aligns the handle. Change this to...

```
handleLeft = l;
```

... to left-align the handle when the sliding drawer is set to slide vertical (i.e. bottom-to-top or top-to-bottom), or change it to...

```
handleLeft = r - handleWidth;
```

... to right-align the handle.

Likewise, if the sliding drawer is set to slide horizontal (i.e. right-to-left or right-to-left), in the `mVertical` is false condition of the `onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)` method, find the following line of code...

```
handleTop = (height - childHeight) / 2;
```

... and change it to...

```
handleTop = t;
```

... to top-align the handle, or...

```
handleTop = b - handleHeight;
```

... to bottom-align the handle. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you ! You saved me a looooot of time trying to align the handler at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Shall I send it to the email address listed in the footer of your website?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using default (vertical) orientation:
If you want to move the drawer handle to the left, set the android:layout_marginRight value of the sliding drawer to some positive number.  Do the opposite android:layout_marginLeft if you want the handle to move to the right.  There is no align right/left per se with the sliding drawer.  If you want a more dynamic alignment, you will have to use layouts to get the desired affect.

Comment: Thanks for the response Android Addict. Setting margins to push the handle to the left or right: is it straightforward getting dimensions right for the different screen sizes/densities to consider or could it get messy?

Comment: If you are using density independent pixels (ie. 30dp) it's very simple:  Display d = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();   
      screenWidth = (int)(d.getWidth());

Comment: No joy. My handle (ImageView) is in a sliding drawer View which neither allows setting margins of the handle in the xml layout file nor doing so programmatically. If I try cast the `View.LayoutParams` object returned from `myHandle.getLayoutParams()` to a `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` object it throws up an exception. I even tried the `myHandle.setRight(0)` method but it's ignored. Looks like I need to go in and change the sliding drawer code but I've had a look and can't figure out where the handle is positioned and how to change it as required. Suggestions most welcome!..

Comment: You need to set the margin on the SlidingDrawer, not the handle.  By virtue, the handle will adjust to the drawer margin.

Here's an example of the starting tag:

<SlidingDrawer
      android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerOptions"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"      
      android:content="@+id/content"
      android:handle="@+id/handle"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

Comment: Also, you can reference resources directly with the handle, you don't need to use an imageview.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion Android Addict but still no joy. Setting the margin of the SlidingDrawer does move the handle **but** it does so by moving the SlidingDrawer (i.e. both the handle and the content) which is not what I want...

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  You want to align relative to the content, not the window.  Sorry, I don't believe that is currently a feature.

Comment: Thanks for the help Android Addict. Appreciate it. I worked out a way to get it to work. Check out my answer...