# I want to do this in my layout of android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I want to show 2 different panels on main layout.The bottom bar will contain two buttons

1. button will slide up and slide down the Settings panel
   and
2. button will open and close contact panel

i have searched a lot but only found slidingdrawer but how can show different panel with the click on buttons?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no images to be displayed.

Comment: See pics below, where is pics...

Comment: where are the pics..??

Comment: Which pics we have to see?

Comment: Why do so many people have to ask the same question? Btw.. where are the pics?

Comment: Sorry i can't post any pics due to my low reputation.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KYCQ4zb.png this is the link of images

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2nhxKh0.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kPsPkGj.png

Comment: for that you can go with fragment......Or you can use View Flipper also..........

Comment: user Fragments , better choice

Answer (score 0):

You could place the Settings and Contact SlidingDrawers each under a RelativeLayout that contains them and have them overlap each other. Then use the buttons as handles aligned next to each other.

Consider the xml code below, I hope it helps ya:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:content="@+id/settings_panel"
    android:handle="@+id/handle1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/handle_tab" 
        android:text="Settings" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="485dp"
        android:background="#000000" >



    </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>


    <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:content="@+id/contact_panel"
    android:handle="@+id/handle2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/handle_tab" 
        android:text="Contact" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="485dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" >



    </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then use the link to help position your Contact and Settings handle (button) properly: [Changing alignment (left, right etc) of SlidingDrawer handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649545/changing-alignment-left-right-etc-of-slidingdrawer-handle)